# Consume RESTful Service from form post

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot

I've built a RESTful service with Spring (java annotation based configuration) which I can execute successfully via Curl. I'm trying to submit files via a HTML Form too, however that's not working.

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        logger.info("POST '/upload'");
        storageService.store(file);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

And I'm submitting a file via Curl as follows:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: multipart/*; boundary=------------BOUNDARY--" -X POST --noproxy localhost, localhost:8080/upload -F "file=@test.txt"
```

Even though my form submission has an input of type file, with the name file, I get this error via a HTML form

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
```

From what I've been investigating, it would seem as if the controller would expect a Model Attribute when the file is submitted via HTML Form, so what could be a good practice to resolve this? Include a controller parameter for a Model Attribute, which would be checked for null value (to distinguish between html form or other submission methods), or would a sort of Proxy controller between the HTML Form and the RESTful service be better?

Comment: Hi! Try change this `@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file` on this `@RequestParam MultipartFile file`

Comment: Sorry! That didn't fix it, the behavior is the same both in Curl and in the HTML form!
It's complaining that the 'file' isn't present in the request I think...

Answer (score 0):

The service looks good. It works fine for me on both CURL and HTML form submit.

Here is my form. Please try using this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post Tool</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sample Requests</h1>            
        <h2>Upload Document</h2>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Choose a file : <input type="file" name="file" multiple/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your spring boot version? Do you use any specific configuration on that?

Comment: Spring boot 1.4.2 releae!

Comment: I've also noticed that, when inspecting the headers of the upload in Firefox, the Content-Type is text/plain, when it clearly shouldn't??

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: After searching for longer, that request payload seems fine.

Comment: Please try once using chrome (i.e. submit the form that I have provided from Chrome browser).

Comment: I can see the rest of the request payload and it carries the files' content in Firefox, but not in Chrome. However the submission doesn't work with Firefox either. nor in IE!

Comment: with the service I've provided?

Comment: Yes, exactly same expect this line storageService.store(file);

Comment: P.S. Chrome v54.0.2840.99 m 64 bit

Comment: It doesn't even run the logger.info line.. It seem as if it's not being able to find the file in the request, however the form's field is properly named as 'file'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128692/discussion-between-notionquest-and-nuno-valente).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, pls check the chat

Answer (score 0):

After more research I got to know that the commons multi part resolver doesn't fare well with the new versions of spring boot. It struggles obtaining POST parameters from forms.
One solution is to use the StandardServletMultipartResolver implementation of the MultipartResolver interface!